# Text input not updating the value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a basic text input but the value is not being updated? For the life of me I can't figure out why, I feel like it's something so simple that I'm overlooking.

```
const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');

return (
  <input
   type="number"   
   step='0.01'
   onChange={(e) => { setInput(e.target.value) }}
   value={input}
  >
  </input>
)
```

Comment: That's a number input, not a text input. Anyway, works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-euclid-s34x2?file=/src/App.js The problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

to use a textInput you should use `<TextInput>` tag in react native.
for example, to create an email input you can write something like this :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const Component= () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <TextInput
      label="Email"
      value={text}
      onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
    />
  );
};
```